# How can you italicize numbers in a mathematical environment with $$?

Tags: math-mode, italic

I just would like to have

```
$$\frac{643,2-759,9}{340,09} = -0,34$$
```

in italic. Is there an easy way? It doesn't work with \textit{} here...

I am looking forward for some help. Thank you!

Comment: You could wrap everything in in `\mathit{}`, so `\[ \mathit{ \frac{1}{2} } \]` would give an italic 1/2

Comment: thank you! that was easier than I thought! ^^